# The total price after repeating order will accumulate but produce wrong value

Tags: c++, function

My codes have logic error (sometimes when repeating order). It calculate the price fine for the first order. But when I repeat order (with while loop inside function listHardware) the total price will be messed up and not producing a correct value(price). Is there something wrong with my calculation inside the calcFunc or with the return value?

```
void listHardware()
{
    int i,j,type,m_type,c_type,r_type,s_type,g_type,quantity=0;
    const int SIZE=3;
    char shopmember,addorder = 'y';
    double price=0;
    const double discount=0.1;

    cout << endl;
    cout << "Membership (Y/N): ";
    cin >> shopmember;

    while(addorder=='Y' || addorder=='y')
    {
    cout << endl << "Select which type of hardware that you want to purchase: ";
    cin >> type;

    if(type==1)
    {
        const char *monitor[SIZE][2]=
        {
            {"BenQ PD3200U", "(RM3000)"},
            {"Acer Predator X34", "(RM4000)"},
            {"Dell UltraSharp UP3218K", "(RM8000)"}
        };

        cout << "Monitors:" << endl;
        for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
        {
            cout << "\t" << i+1 << ". ";
            for(j=0;j<2;j++)
            {
                cout << monitor[i][j] << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
        cout << endl << "Enter which Monitor you would like to purchase: ";
        cin >> m_type; //monitor
        cout << endl << "How many Monitor would you like to purchase?" << endl;
        cin >> quantity;
    }
    if(type==2)
    {
        const char *cpu[SIZE][2]=
        {
            {"AMD Ryzen 7 2700X", "(RM1200)"},
            {"Intel Core i5-8600K", "(RM1200)"},
            {"Intel Core i9-7980XE", "(RM8000)"}
        };

        cout << "CPU:" << endl;
        for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
        {
            cout << "\t" << i+1 << ". ";
            for(j=0;j<2;j++)
            {
                cout << cpu[i][j] << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
        cout << endl << "Enter which CPU would you like to purchase: ";
        cin >> c_type; //cpu
        cout << endl << "How many CPU would you like to purchase?" << endl;
        cin >> quantity;
    }
    if(type==3)
    {
        const char *ram[SIZE][2]=
        {
            {"Patriot Viper Elite 8GB DDR4-2400MHz", "(RM400)"},
            {"G.Skill Ripjaws V 16GB DDR4-2400MHz", "(RM1200)"},
            {"Corsair Dominator Platinum 32GB DDR4-3333MHz", "(RM2000)"}
        };

        cout << "RAM:" << endl;
        for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
        {
            cout << "\t" << i+1 << ". ";
            for(j=0;j<2;j++)
            {
                cout << ram[i][j] << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
        cout << endl << "Enter which RAM would you like to purchase: ";
        cin >> r_type; //ram
        cout << endl << "How many RAM would you like to purchase?" << endl;
        cin >> quantity;
    }
    if(type==4)
    {
        const char *ssd[SIZE][2]=
        {
            {"Samsung 860 Pro 1TB", "(RM1250)"},
            {"Crucial MX500 1TB", "(RM600)"},
            {"WD Blue 2TB", "(RM1600)"}
        };

        cout << "SSD:" << endl;
        for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
        {
            cout << "\t" << i+1 << ". ";
            for(j=0;j<2;j++)
            {
                cout << ssd[i][j] << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
        cout << endl << "Enter which SSD would you like to purchase: ";
        cin >> s_type; //ssd
        cout << endl << "How many SSD would you like to purchase?" << endl;
        cin >> quantity;
    }
    if(type==5)
    {
        const char *gcard[SIZE][2]=
        {
            {"Nvidia GeForce RTX 2080 Ti", "(RM4000)"},
            {"Nvidia GeForce GTX 1080 Ti", "(RM2900)"},
            {"AMD Radeon RX 580 8GB", "(RM2100)"}
        };

        cout << "Graphic Card:" << endl;
        for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
        {
            cout << "\t" << i+1 << ". ";
            for(j=0;j<2;j++)
            {
                cout << gcard[i][j] << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
        cout << endl << "Enter which Graphic Card would you like to purchase: ";
        cin >> g_type; //gpu
        cout << endl << "How many Graphic Card would you like to purchase?" << endl;
        cin >> quantity;
    }

    price = calcFunc(m_type,c_type,r_type,s_type,g_type,quantity,price,shopmember); //function call

    cout << setfill ('-') << setw (55) << "-" << endl;
    cout << "Total price for now (not including membership discount): RM" << price << endl;
    cout << setfill ('-') << setw (55) << "-" << endl;

    cout << "Do you want to purchase more? Press y for yes." << endl;
    cin >> addorder;
    }
    cout << setfill ('-') << setw (55) << "-" << endl;
    if (shopmember == 'y' || shopmember == 'Y')
        cout << "Total Price: RM" << price-(price*discount) << endl;
    else
        cout << "Total Price: RM" << price << endl;
    cout << setfill ('-') << setw (55) << "-" << endl;
}

//

double calcFunc(int m_type,int c_type,int r_type, int s_type, int g_type,int quantity,double price, char shopmember)
{
    if(m_type==1) //monitor
    {
        price+=3000*quantity;
    }
    else if(m_type==2) //monitor
    {
        price+=4000*quantity;
    }
    else if(m_type==3) //monitor
    {
        price+=8000*quantity;
    }

    if(c_type==1) //cpu
    {
        price+=1200*quantity;
    }
    else if(c_type==2) //cpu
    {
        price+=1200*quantity;
    }
    else if(c_type==3) //cpu
    {
        price+=8000*quantity;
    }

    if(r_type==1) //ram
    {
        price+=400*quantity;
    }
    else if(r_type==2) //ram
    {
        price+=1200*quantity;
    }
    else if(r_type==3) //ram
    {
        price+=2000*quantity;
    }

    if(s_type==1) //ssd
    {
        price+=1250*quantity;
    }
    else if(s_type==2) //ssd
    {
        price+=600*quantity;
    }
    else if(s_type==3) //ssd
    {
        price+=1600*quantity;
    }

    if(g_type==1) //gpu
    {
        price+=4000*quantity;
    }
    else if(g_type==2) //gpu
    {
        price+=2900*quantity;
    }
    else if(g_type==3) //gpu
    {
        price+=2100*quantity;
    } 
    return price;
}
```

Comment: Why do you ask for quantity if only the last one matters?

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher I'm sorry but what do you mean by only the last one matters? Is the any problem with the quantity variable inside the calculation?

Comment: It would probably help a lot if you break down the code into its common repeated parts and make those into __separate functions__. Every item that's for sale has the same attributes (category, model name, price) and every sale follows the same process (get category, get model, get quantity, loop through more items, check for discount, print final price). Breaking things into functions means that you can test the individual functions by feeding them test data and looking at the output.

Comment: @Shizu bercause quantity is the same variable and you override it all the time.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher okay that makes sense. So I should use different variable of quantity for each types of hardware right? I'll try it now. Thanks!

Comment: And as the other said, refactor your code in functions.

Comment: See `tolower` or `toupper` so you only have to make one comparison.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I'm sorry, how can that affect my price value?

Comment: It affects your input, "Y" vs "y".

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't initialize your `*_type` variables so they have unpredicted values which may affect values returned from `calcFunc()`.

Second, you don't reset your `*_type` variables when entering the loop, so if in the first iteration you chose monitor type 2, i.e. `m_type = 2`, then in the second iteration it will be passed again to `calcFunc()` even if in that second iteration you chose cpu. The monitor will be included in the total price twice.